# clean way to os.walk once python

Tags: python, os.path

I want to talk a few directories once, and just grab the info for one dir. Currently I use:

```
i = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(home_path):
    if i >= 1:
        return 1
    i += 1
    for this_dir in dirs:
       do stuff
```

This is horribly tedious of course. When I want to walk the subdir under it, I do the same 5 lines, using j, etc...

What is the shortest way to grab all dirs and files underneath a single directory in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can empty the `dirs` list and `os.walk()` won't recurse:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(home_path):
    for dir in dirs:
        # do something with each directory
    dirs[:] = []  # clear directories.
```

Note the `dirs[:] =` slice assignment; we are replacing the elements in `dirs` (and not the list referred to by `dirs`) so that `os.walk()` will not process deleted directories.

This only works if you keep the `topdown` keyword argument to `True`, from the [documentation of `os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again.

Alternatively, use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) and filter the names out into directories and files yourself:

```
dirs = []
files = []
for name in os.listdir(home_path):
    path = os.path.join(home_path, name)
    if os.isdir(path):
        dirs.append(name)
    else:
        files.append(name)
```

Comment: ty Mr. Pieters, doesn't get much easier than that